# Suave not showing static file

Tags: f#, suave

So I have my server set up very simply.  If the path is of the form `/article/something`, it should serve up the static file `something.html` within the folder `static`.  For some reason, the `Files.file` webpart is apparently returning `None`.  I tacked on the `OK "File Displayed"` webpart to verify that this is the case.  The `OK` never executes.

```
let app =
    choose [
        pathScan "/article/%s" (fun article ->
                                  let name = sprintf "%s.html" article
                                  Console.WriteLine name
                                  Files.file name >=> OK "File Displayed")
    ]

let config =
    { defaultConfig with homeFolder = Some (Path.GetFullPath "./static") }

[<EntryPoint>]
let main args =
    startWebServer config app
    0
```

Interestingly enough, the `Console.WriteLine name` line executes perfectly and I see `something.html` in the console window when I execute this.  It appears the problem is exclusively `Files.file name` returning None.

The file `something.html` definitely exists in the static folder, so that's not the problem .

Any ideas on what might be causing this?

Comment: Have you verified that `File.file name` indeed returns `None`?

Comment: I would also check to what absolute path does "./static" expand, because that could be relative to the working directory of the process, which depends on who launches it and from where

Comment: @HonzaBrestan thanks!  That wasn't exactly what was going on, but it helped me find the problem.  I'm using Windows, so it didn't like the fact that I said `"./static"` instead of `".\\static"`

Answer (score 0):

Here are some parts to troubleshoot static file serving issues

```
    let troubleShootExtensionPart extensionToCheck :WebPart =
        fun ctx ->
            match extensionToCheck with
            | null | "" -> ServerErrors.INTERNAL_ERROR "Extension Error not supplied, part is not set up correctly"
            | x when not <| x.StartsWith "." -> ServerErrors.INTERNAL_ERROR "Extensions start with a '.', part is not set up correctly"
            | _ ->
                let mtm = ctx.runtime.mimeTypesMap
                match mtm extensionToCheck with
                | None ->
                    sprintf "%s is not supported by the mime types map, compose your mime type with the `defaultMimeTypesMap`" extensionToCheck
                    |> RequestErrors.FORBIDDEN
                | Some x ->
                    sprintf "%s is supported and uses '%s', compression on? : %A" extensionToCheck x.name x.compression
                    |> OK
            |> fun wp -> wp ctx
```

example consumption with a wildcard so if no routes match you get some diagnostic info

```
#if DEBUG
pathScan "/checkExtension/%s" (fun name -> troubleShootExtensionPart name)
// catch all
(fun ctx -> sprintf "404, also homeFolder resolves to %s" (Path.GetFullPath ".") |> RequestErrors.NOT_FOUND |> fun wp -> wp ctx)
#endif
```